# MongoDB retriving a part of a field

Tags: mongodb

I have a table similar to following

```
 field1
============
sssss(x)sdfs
ddd(d)fsdfsd
adf(d)dfssdf
sdf(x)sdfsdf
```

I want retrive all distinct text in parentheses in field1, How can I get following output?

```
subStirng
===========
x
d
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to run a map-reduce job to create a collection like

```
sssss x sdfs
ddd d fsdfsd
adf d dfssdf
sdf x sdfsdf
```

At that point distinct can be run or you can program the reduce function in m-r to get the following

```
x
d
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
> db.test.insert({"field1":"sssss(x)sdfs"})
> db.test.insert({"field1":"ddd(d)fsdfsd"})

> db.test.find().forEach(function(foo){print(foo.field1.match(/\w*\((\w)\)\w*/)[1])})
x
d
```

I find out that the method above don't show the `distinct` result.

Or try map/reduce function?

```
m = function(){emit(this.field1.match(/\w*\((\w)\)\w*/)[1], 1)}
r = function(key, values){ return 1;}
db.test.mapReduce(m, r, {out:{inline:1}})

{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "d",
                    "value" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "x",
                    "value" : 1
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 399,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 30003,
            "emit" : 30003,
            "reduce" : 302,
            "output" : 2
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Or... maybe you can find the substring before insertion and store it in another field. I think this way will be faster.

Comment: Thanks, I tested forEach in a collection that have 30,000 entery, and it run very very slowly.